# narrowing a union type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
export async function loadInitialProps(routes: AsyncRouteProps[], pathname: string, ctx: any): Promise<InitialProps> {
  const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];

  const match = routes.find((route: AsyncRouteProps) => {
    const matched = matchPath(pathname, route);

    if (matched && route.component && isAsyncComponent(route.component)) {
      promises.push(
        route.component.load
          ? route.component.load().then(() => route.component.getInitialProps({ matched, ...ctx }))
          : route.component.getInitialProps({ matched, ...ctx })
      );
    }

    return !!matched;
  });

  return {
    match,
    data: (await Promise.all(promises))[0]
  };
}
```

I thought I could narrow the union type with my `isAsyncComponent` guarded function:

```
export function isAsyncComponent(Component: AsyncRouteableComponent): Component is AsyncRouteComponentType<any> {
  return (<AsyncRouteComponentType<any>>Component).load !== undefined;
}
```

My `AsyncRouteableComponent` type is a union type:

```
export type AsyncRouteableComponent<Props = any> =
  | AsyncRouteComponentType<RouteComponentProps<Props>>
  | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<Props>>
  | React.ComponentType<Props>;
```

But typescript thinks the code in the resolved promise function `route.component.load().then(() => route.component.getInitialProps({ matched, ...ctx }))` is not the type I expect.

```
if (matched && route.component && isAsyncComponent(route.component)) {
  promises.push(
    route.component.load
      ? route.component.load().then(() => route.component.getInitialProps({ matched, ...ctx }))
      : route.component.getInitialProps({ matched, ...ctx })
  );
}
```

I get the error message:

> ```
> Property 'getInitialProps' does not exist on type
> 'AsyncRouteableComponent<any>'.   Property 'getInitialProps' does not
> exist on type 'ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any,
> StaticContext>>'.
> ```

So it does not appear to have narrowed it down after my guard clause.

I can fix it by doing this but I thought the guard function would mean I did not need to do this:

```
if (matched && route.component && isAsyncComponent(route.component)) {
  const component = route.component as AsyncRouteComponentType<any>;

  promises.push(
    component.load
      ? component.load().then(() => component.getInitialProps({ matched, ...ctx }))
      : component.getInitialProps({ matched, ...ctx })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrowing for a mutable local variable such as `route` does not apply inside callbacks such as your `then` callback because TypeScript doesn't trust that the local variable won't be reassigned before the callback executes.  See [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7662) for a little more information.  The workaround is to copy `route` (or `route.component`) to a `const` variable before you call the guard function.